# What insulation should I use when converting a metal shed to a pool house?

Tags: shed

I need to know which insulation I need for my 20x12 metal shed.  I am making it into a pool house. Bathroom, sink, bed. Is made of 2x4s, and plywood floor on beam, sheet metal siding, aluminum type doors, 2 small windows.

I live in north Texas, summer can be over 100 degrees and some winters 10 degrees for a few days.

Am putting in ductless air/heat unit.  Using Lifeproof Luxury vinyl plank flooring.

Studs are mostly 22 in apart, some 18 and 30 inches apart. Ceiling is studs and sheet metal also.

Also, can I add this before my electrician and plumber get started?  Or wait.?  on a budget, need cheapest solution, but do NOT want to deal with roll fiberglass insulation.

Thank you

Comment: If you put insulation in the walls, your electrician and plumber will spend more time doing their jobs because they'll have to pull it out to run their wire/pipes. Unless, of course, you're having them run those on the interior, finished surface. They'll probably leave it out instead of reinstalling it, too, which means that you'll have to reinstall it.

Comment: So you've eliminated fiberglass, which is more or less the default for this type of thing. What options does that leave? A bib system with blown cellulose? Spray urethane? What's the question, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Cheapest solution (build cost) - don't insulate, costs a lot to run and performs poorly.

Cheapest solution (lifetime cost) - insulate well, costs more to build, less to run, performs better.

When to install - after your electrician and plumber are done, because doing it before they are done is going to increase your cost for them to do their parts of the job, and you'll have to repair the insulation after they are done.

Type of insulation - there are many. They all work, they all have costs which vary with your location and method of installation, they have varying levels of performance which sometimes but not always follow the varying levels of cost. There is no one right answer to be given here, it's a choice you have to make.